# El uso y el no uso de los artículos con la palabra "tiempo"

Tags: gramática, artículos

Soy consciente de que usamos el artículo indefinido con la palabra "tiempo" para decir "some time" y me parece que eso forma parte de las frases comunes (como en inglés):

"*Muchos artistas y escritores consideraban que pasar **un** tiempo en París era indispensable*"

*"¿Darse **un** tiempo en pareja funciona?"*

"*¿En qué os puede ayudar un psicólogo de pareja si os tomáis **un** tiempo?*"

Por favor, corríjanme si me equivoco y si has otras situaciones en las que se puede usar el artículo indefinido con "tiempo".

Al mismo tiempo, no entiendo cuando tenemos que usar el artículo definido u omitirlo antes de "tiempo". Encontré esa explicación en https://www.spanishlearninglab.com/los-articulos-definidos-en-espanol/:

"*...en español usamos los artículos definidos antes de los sustantivos abstractos, es decir aquellos que no tienen una existencia material como TIEMPO (time) o AMOR (love). En inglés, por ejemplo, se dice “Love is a feeling…” pero en español diríamos “El amor es un sentimiento”, agregando el artículo correspondiente al sustantivo AMOR. De esta manera, siempre diremos “**El** tiempo” o “El amor”, especialmente cuando estas palabras funcionen como el sujeto de una oración, p. ej. “**El** tiempo es oro” (Time is gold).*"

Pero en este artículo https://coachdelaprofesional.com/como-sacar-tiempo/ encontre las mismas frases tanto con el artículo definido como sin él:

*"Yo he hablado con personas que quieren su propio negocio o apuntarse  a alguno de mis cursos pero no saben de donde sacar **el** tiempo."*

*"te gustaría poder sacar tiempo para hacer lo que de verdad te importa?"*

*"No necesito razones, no necesito sacar tiempo, siempre tengo tiempo."*

*"lo hago tenga **el** tiempo que tenga."*

En otro fuente encontré también "sacar un tiempo":

*"Te invitamos a sacar **un** tiempo para reflexionar sobre aquellas emociones y pensamientos que te quitan la tranquilidad"*

Por eso, a veces no entiendo cómo usar los artículos (u omitirlos) con "tiempo". Tal vez se aplica a otros sustantivos abstractos en español, cómo aquí:

"No tenemos prisa"
"La flexibiladad para evitar la prisa"

Entonces, ¿cuál es la regla en cuanto al uso de los artículos con los sustantuvos abstractos?

Comment: Es **una** fuente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedo responder sobre estas oraciones en particular:

1. "Yo he hablado con personas que quieren su propio negocio o apuntarse a alguno de mis cursos pero no saben de donde sacar el tiempo."
2. "te gustaría poder sacar tiempo para hacer lo que de verdad te importa?"
3. "No necesito razones, no necesito sacar tiempo, siempre tengo tiempo."
4. "lo hago tenga el tiempo que tenga."

En estos casos vale la regla del comienzo: “tiempo” sin artículo significa “algo de tiempo” o bien es parte de una frase hecha (“sacar tiempo”, “tener tiempo”). En las frases hechas o fijas suele no usarse artículo, especialmente con “tener”.

Donde se usa el artículo definido es porque este período de tiempo del que se habla es definido. Esto ocurre frecuentemente cuando alguna otra cosa modifica la palabra “tiempo”, por ejemplo: “el tiempo **que tenga**”. En la oración nº 1 no hay ningún modificador, pero está implícito que “el tiempo” significa “el tiempo **que sea necesario para** tener un negocio propio o apuntarse a un curso”.

El artículo indefinido se puede usar para enfatizar la idea de “algo de tiempo, cierta cantidad de tiempo”. “¿Tienes tiempo para revisar esto?” y “¿Tienes un tiempo para revisar esto?” significan prácticamente lo mismo, pero en el segundo caso suena como más tentativo o amable, como si dijéramos que hace falta solamente “un poco de tiempo”.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que la respuesta a esta pregunta necesita de un análisis más detallado o profundo. Por ahora diría que si se dirige a otra persona se omite o se usa más 'el', pero cuando es para uno mismo o para un mismo en relación a otros se usa 'un'.

En mi esp esto es correcto: 'No saben de donde **sacar** el tiempo'. <=ok(we don't even know where to find the time, his schedule's tight),

...pero esto no: 'Te gustaría poder **sacar** tiempo para'<=no=> 'Te gustaría tener (el) tiempo para'(I'd like to have some time to do)

...y esto tampoco: Te invitamos a **sacar** un tiempo para...<=no=> Te invitamos a **darte** UN tiempo(=give you some time to yourself).

Varía también si es una orden o sugerencia hacia otra pers.

- 'Date un tiempo para'=give yourself some time to, get some time, take time to/'darle un tiempo'(=to give her/him some time)/dale tiempo=give him time.

También hay que considerar que en el español se usa más el artículo que en el inglés o al menos eso es en la práctica y que al decir 'un' tiempo nos referimos a algo más acotado, conocido o estimable a diferencia de si se omite o se usa 'el' donde en ese caso hablamos de algo más amplio o abstracto.

> "Lo hago tenga **el** tiempo que tenga."
> <-Es como decir "lo hago tenga el tiempo o no", es decir, lo hago sí o sí, incluso si el tiempo me es insuficiente.

- "Lo hago tenga **un** tiempo que tenga."
  <-No parece posible porque en ese caso acota el tiempo a algo limitado que no permite esa chance de lograrlo.
- "Lo hago tenga tiempo que tenga."
  <-No parece posible omitir el artículo, pero si es posible si se  dice:
- "Lo hago tenga tiempo o no."

En cambio:

- "Lo hago tenga **el** tiempo o no."
  Es más enfático.

Estos dos últimos ejemplos me da la impresión de que varían según la región.

En el ejemplo de prisa no lo expresaría con esas palabras, así que espera otras respuestas con otras variantes de español donde haya más o menos libertad para usar o no el artículo definido e indefinido intercambiablemente.

¿Creo que estos son ejemplos de español mexicano? Serían interesante contrastarlos con el peninsular.

> "Muchos artistas y escritores consideraban que pasar **un** tiempo en París era indispensable".
> <-Acá «pasar el tiempo» me suena a pasar el rato(hang out) en cambio «pasar un tiempo» es algo como un viaje de esparcimiento, y en el caso de «pasar tiempo» no especifíca que tan frecuentes o en que épocas ocurre.

> "¿Darse **un** tiempo en pareja funciona?"

- «Darse **un** tiempo» => Un tiempo corto distanciados para refrescar la relación y luego posiblemente reconciliarse.
- «Darse tiempo» => No se especifíca cuanto tiempo va a durar el distanciamiento o simplemente es para referirse al acto de darse tiempo ('The act of giving your time')
- «Darse (**el**) tiempo» => Para hacer algo(p.ej: para escucharse, el uno al otro todos los días).

Comment: Me gustan tus ultimas frases.